# Highcharts / HighStock gapUnit breaks navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I set `gapUnit = 'value'` in order to specify a `gapSize` in milliseconds.
This was done like this:

```
plotOptions: {
     series: {
                dataGrouping: {enabled: true},
                showInNavigator: true
            },
            line: {
                gapSize: 15 * 60 * 1000,
                gapUnit: 'value'
            }
        }
```

Setting `gapUnit` breaks the `navigator` at the bottom.
It remains empty. Any idea why?

#### Examples

Here is an [official working example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/series-gapsize/). It [no longer works](https://jsfiddle.net/stroobandt/f57qs9a4/) when changing the `gapUnit` to `'value'`: https://jsfiddle.net/stroobandt/f57qs9a4/

Comment: Please provide some live working example that illustrates your problem. This article should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KamilKulig I have added a working and non-working example of what looks like a Highstock bug.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a bug. You can report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: I did so; see: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7521

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Set `gapUnit` and `gapSize` separately for `navigator`

Setting `gapUnit` and `gapSize` separately for the `navigator` restores default behaviour.

```
navigator: {
    series: {
        gapUnit: `relative`,
        gapSize: 0,
    },
},
```

See also: https://jsfiddle.net/stroobandt/e6k3h550/